# Empty response for HTTP 503 with JAX-RS and Tomcat?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I have an JAX-RS resource (in my war deployed in Tomcat) which should return HTTP 503 under some circumstances with an empty body. The implementation of my resource looks like this

```java
@GET
@Path("/alive")
public Response alive() {
    Response result = noContent().build();

    if (shouldReturn503()) 
        result = Response.status(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                         .build();

    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately Tomcat adds always a HTML page to the response. How can I force Tomcat to return a HTTP 503 status and no body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```java
result = Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).entity("").build();
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE constant?  Are you looking for this?:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).build();
```

I get an empty body when I do that.